# What does ebp+4 have to do with a 2 dimensional array?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

What is the `ebp + 4` in the code in line 4? I know `ebp + 4` is the return address. I also know that it points to the part right after a call to a subroutine. But I'm not calling a subroutine in the code below, it is just a array. (`x = a[I][J];`)

```
mov eax, [ebp - 44] ; ebp - 44 is i’s location 
sal eax, 1 ; multiple i by 2

add eax, [ebp - 48] ; add j
mov eax, [ebp + 4*eax - 40] ; ebp - 40 is the address of a[0][0]

mov [ebp - 52], eax ; store result into x (at ebp - 52)
```

Please tell me what the purpose of the `ebp+4` in line 4 is used for.

Comment: There's no +4 there, it is [ebp-40 + (4*ex)].  Standard array indexing code.

Answer (score 3):

It might be more apparent if it were presented as:

```
mov eax, [4*eax + ebp - 40]
```

The `4*eax` is simply scaling the index calculated by `2*i + j` (I assume that the array has wo elements per row) by the size of each element (4 bytes).